# Load highcharts data with laravel and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, highcharts

i have this issue for loading data for a highcharts chart.

From the response of my controller i get the following data:

```
[['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]
```

And the call of the ajax is working fine, however, the chart is not displaying.

**EDIT:**
I got it almost working, however there is something strange. The whole code with ajax is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function handleData( responseData ) {
    // do what you want with the data
    console.log('Inside handle data function: ' + responseData);
        // Radialize the colors
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
            };
        });
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Investigadores por grado académico'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                        style: {
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                        },
                        connectorColor: 'silver'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Porcentaje:',
                data: responseData/*THE DATA ARE NOT WELL RECEIVED HERE. But if i type "[['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]" directly, it does work! So why with the variable it doesn't work?*/
            }]
        });//Fin de la función de highcharts


    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $.ajax({
          url: '{{URL::route("query01")}}',
          type: 'GET',
          async: true,
          dataType: 'text',
          success: function(datos,status, XHR) {
              console.log('Data inside ajax is: ' + datos);
              handleData(datos);
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is not working, since the data are not being well received somehow, because if i use the ResponseData variable that has the data, the chart is not displayed, however, if i write directly the string

```
[['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]
```

It does work.
Indeed in the console.log i see the variable `responseData` does have that data string!

*console.log()*:

```
Data inside ajax is: [['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]
Inside handle data function: [['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]
```

And the pie chart is not showing properly. I only can see several lines saying *slice 0.0%*
Any ideas?

Comment: Why you removed `dataType: "json",` ? Set it back, otherwise your data will be transported as string, so it won't work.. If you set `dataType: "json",` and this doesn't work, then your JSON is incorrect. I would start with replacing `'` -> `"`.

Comment: @PawełFus If i pass it as json, the data is lost and the console.log is not even displayed. I am passing a string data. Json datatype is not being processed correctly, it has a different format!

Comment: @PawełFus If i get the *json* data from the database, the data looks like this: `[{"Grado Acad\u00e9mico":"Doctorado","subtotal":79},{"Grado Acad\u00e9mico":"Maestr\u00eda","subtotal":6},{"Grado Acad\u00e9mico":"Licenciatura","subtotal":1}]` This kind of array is not going to be well processed by the highcharts. And moreover in the log.console i get `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` and the chart is not being well displayed. That is why i made a function to get the data simply like this: `[['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]`.

Comment: But your current one is some string, which isn't suitable format for Highcharts... As I said before, replace single quotes with double quotes: `'` -> `"`. Then you may be able to do this: `data: JSON.parse(responseData)`

Comment: @PawełFus I get an error: *SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data*

Comment: That means your string isn't proper JSON, have you changes single quotes? Test your JSON, for example using [this](http://json.parser.online.fr).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71100/discussion-between-pathros-and-pawel-fus).

Answer (score 0):

In first listing this code

```
$(function () {
```

means event 'document ready'

In second listing, where are you calling your function `grafica`?
As I see, you need to call it in ajax `success` function

Comment: Yeah, now i have edited the code. The strange thing is that the data is somehow passed not properly to the function. If i use the variable `responseData` The chart is not displayed. However, if i write directly the string data `[['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]` then it does work. Indeed in the console.log i see the variable does have that data string!

Comment: Try to check type of your response. Maybe you should use string, but get json from your server. You can try to manually set `datos` in your `success` function to string data from your example `[['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]`

Comment: I have tried `dataType: 'text'` and still got the same problem :/ I don't understand, in the console.log I get the string as it should be.

Comment: Are you sure that you need  to use `string` type of data in highcharts? This `"[['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]"` and this `[['Doctorado', 91.86],['Maestría', 6.98],['Licenciatura', 1.16]]` are a different types. First is a string and second is an array. Check it and if you need `json` in your `handleData` function try to use JSON.parse for your ajax response before pass it to `handleData` function. You can check type of your variable with `console.log(typeof(someVar))`, in your case `console.log(typeof(responseData))`